# How do I prevent my Ubuntu from repeatedly switching off the Mirror Display mode?

Tags: display, hdmi

I want my computer to display an external monitor as Mirror, so I configured it as such.

However, that external monitor has input options from both my computer's HDMI and also from a DVD player, and whenever I switch to using the DVD player, the computer's "Mirror" setting is lost. How can I have the computer stay in "Mirror"  mode?